# $\hom_R(R/(a),R/(b))$ is zero if $a,b$ are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I want to show that if $a,b$ are relatively prime elements in a UFD $R$ then there are no nonzero $R$-module homomorphisms between $R/(a)$ and $R/(b)$. I think this is easier if the ring is a PID but I'm having trouble even in that case.

Comment: In a PID, there exist $r,s\in R$ such that $ar + bs = 1$ because $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. If you have a morphism $\phi : R/(a)\to R/(b),$ it is enough to determine where $1 + (a)$ goes. But then $\phi(1 + (a)) = \phi(ar + bs + (a)) = \phi(bs + (a)) = b\phi(s + (a)) = 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\colon R/(a)\to R/(b)$ be a module homomorphism. Since $R/(a)$ is cyclic, generated by $1+(a)$, it is enough to know what $f(1+(a))$ is. Say $f(1+(a)) = r+(b)$. Then we have
$$ 0 = f(0+(a)) = f(a+(a)) = f(a(1+(a))) = af(1+(a)) = a(r+(b)) = ar+(b).$$
Thus, $ar\in (b)$, hence $b|ar$. Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and we are in a UFD, we conclude that $b|r$, and hence that $r+(b) = 0+(b)$. So $f$ is the zero map.